# How to render models.ManyToManyField checkbox widgets horizontally?

Tags: django, django-models, checkbox, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model name App_type and SOA.

```
class SOA(models.Model):
      app_type        = models.ManyToManyField(App_type, verbose_name='Application Type')
```

In my forms.py

```
class SoaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    app_type = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
                                          queryset=App_type.objects.all(), label='Application Type')
    class Meta:
        model = SOA
```

The field form is rendered vertically in django admin consuming too much space. Is there a way to render the field form horizantally? Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Something like this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2236/)?

Comment: I tried using the snippet in this way `app_type = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=ColumnCheckboxSelectMultiple(),                                         queryset=App_type.objects.all(), label='Application Type')` but still not working.

Comment: I change 2 things in the snippets to make it work which I will explain below. The snippets is so useful in the type of problem. Thanks for the links Karthikr.

Comment: Glad it helped. Do post the answer so it could help the community in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [karthikr pointed out](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2236/) the snippets really works after a super minor adjustment.

The original snippets within `def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):`:

```
   for column in columns:
        ...
        str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])
        for i, (option_value, option_label) in column:
            ...
            option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
            output.append(u'<li><label%s>%s %s</label></li>' % (
                    label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
        output.append(u'</ul>')
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

modified to this:

```
for column in columns:
        ...
        str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])

        output.append(u'<li>')                               ## added

        for i, (option_value, option_label) in column:            
            ...
            option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label)) 

            ##<li> & </li> deleted
            output.append(u'<label%s>%s %s</label>' % (  
                    label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
    ## added </li>
    output.append(u'</li></ul>')
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay post. I have a wifi hardware prob. ><

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using Crispy fields. Very simple and usefull. 
Plus you can use Bootstrap toolkit. And yours life will be more esier.

http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/1.1.1/tags.html